# Не определяются функции cv2 (OpenCv)

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, cv2

если у кого то не определяются функции, то возможно вам поможет это решение

```
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             ↡
```

Answer (score 1):

Из папки, в которую установлен OpenCV скопировать файл: cv2.pyd file.

Вставить данный файл ( cv2.pyd file) в папку C:\Python310\DLLs

Вставить данный файл ( cv2.pyd file) в папку C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages

Зайти в PyCharm IDE зайти в Settings>Python Interpreter и изменить на 1-ю
версию .

Перезапустить PyCharm.